# Помогите решить задачку по пайтону

Tags: python, python-3.x, шахматы

Помогите решить задачку по пайтону.

```
I = int(input("ведите номер столбца 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 "))
Nomer_stroki = input("Введите номер строки a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h ")


if Nomer_stroki==a and i%2==0:
    print("Beloe")

elif Nomer_stroki==b and i%2!=0 and i<=8:
    print("Beloe")

elif Nomer_stroki==c and i%2==0 and i<=8:
    print("Beloe")

elif Nomer_stroki==d and i%2!=0 and i<=8:
    print("Beloe")

elif Nomer_stroki==e and i%2==0 and i<=8:
print("Beloe")

elif Nomer_stroki==f and i%2!=0 and i<=8:
    print("Beloe")

elif Nomer_stroki==g and i%2==0 and i<=8:
    print("Beloe")

else :
    print("Chernoe")
    print("Такой клетки нету")
```

Суть простая шахматная доска, **`8х8`**, определить цвет квадрата, **`1а`** - черная. Нужно чтобы я ввел и по горизонтали и по вертикали, программка определила где черная, где белая.

Проблема в том, что я задаю в переменную `Nomer_stroki` столбец и пытаюсь его сравнить соответствует ли он номерку заданному, но он пишет что номер строки не задан. Как это исправить ?

Comment: для начала: `if Nomer_stroki=="a" and i%2==0:`. вам нужно ввод со строковым значением "a", а вы сравниваете с переменной `a`, которую не задавали

Answer (score 1):

Немного магии через остаток от деления для определения четного числа: если сумма индексов четная, то это черная клетка, иначе белая

Пример:

```
rows = '12345678'
cols = 'abcdefgh'

i = '1'
j = 'a'
idx_i, idx_j = rows.find(i), cols.find(j)
if idx_i == -1 or idx_j == -1:
    print("Такой клетки нет")
else:
    print('Черное' if (idx_i + idx_j) % 2 == 0 else 'Белое')
```

---

**PS.**

Визуально это можно так увидеть:

```
for idx_i in range(8):
    for idx_j in range(8):
        print('*' if (idx_i + idx_j) % 2 == 0 else ' ', end=' ')

    print()
```

Результат:

```
*   *   *   *   
  *   *   *   * 
*   *   *   *   
  *   *   *   * 
*   *   *   *   
  *   *   *   * 
*   *   *   *   
  *   *   *   *
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i = int(input("ведите номер столбца 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 "))
Nomer_stroki = input("Введите номер строки a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h ")

list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']

if Nomer_stroki == 'a' and i % 2 == 0 and i <= 8:
    print("Beloe")

elif Nomer_stroki == 'b' and i % 2 != 0 and i <= 8:
    print("Beloe")

elif Nomer_stroki == 'c' and i % 2 == 0 and i <= 8:
    print("Beloe")

elif Nomer_stroki == 'd' and i % 2 !=0 and i <= 8:
    print("Beloe")

elif Nomer_stroki == 'e' and i % 2 == 0 and i <= 8:
    print("Beloe")

elif Nomer_stroki == 'f' and i % 2 != 0 and i <= 8:
    print("Beloe")

elif Nomer_stroki == 'g' and i % 2 == 0 and i <= 8:
    print("Beloe")
elif i not in list1 or Nomer_stroki not in list2:
    print("Такой клетки нету")
else:
    print("Chernoe")
```

Comment: Спасибо добрый души человечешко, пазл сложился =_

Comment: Если вам помог мой ответ, то, пожалуйста, отметьте его как правильный)

Answer (score 0):

Ну примерно как-то так сделал бы я

```
columns = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
lines = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']

print("Доступные столбцы:", columns)
print("Доступные строки:", lines)

column = int(input('Введите номер столбца: '))
line = str(input('Введите букву строки: '))

if (column in columns) and (line in lines):
    column = columns.index(column) + 1
    line = lines.index(line) + 1
    
    if (column % 2 != 0) and (line % 2 != 0):
        print("Черное поле")
    elif (column % 2 == 0) and (line % 2 == 0):
        print("Черное поле")
    elif (column % 2 != 0) and (line % 2 == 0):
        print("Белое поле")
    elif (column % 2 == 0) and (line % 2 != 0):
        print("Белое поле")
else:
    print("Строка или столбец не найдены.")
```